# Fast import of data from SQL Server database into RSTudio

Tags: r, sql-server, database, performance, import

I am trying to ingest a large amount of data (a timestamp every second, with 222 variables for months) from an SQL Server database.

However, RStudio takes around 30 seconds to import just one day.

This is the actual code I use to import the data:

```r
library(RODBC)

table_name <- "[dbo].[sqldata]"

query_string <- paste0("SELECT * FROM ", table_name)

df <- sqlQuery(connect_to_db(),query_string)
odbcCloseAll()
```

Is there a way to import the data faster?

Could importing data each day and then using 'rbind' to unite them be faster?

Comment: (1) I've often found `DBI` and `odbc` to be faster in some situations, but I don't think it's always the case and have no clear evidence to say that it will always be true. Lacking that, (2) use the bulk command-line utilities: `bcp` or `sqlcmd`. The download is *much* faster, albeit needing post-download processing since neither complies with (e.g., CSV) "norms".

Comment: Depending (heavily) on what your next steps are, using `dbplyr` can be very effective - your `dplyr` R code will be translated to SQL and executed on the server, and only the calculated results will be loaded to R.

Answer (score 3):

Have you see this?

https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver/wiki/benchmarking

There is something called '`dbBulkCopy`'. Look into that. Also, check out this link.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-data.html#RODBC

I have never had a problem with the traditional RODBC method of grabbing data from SQL Server.

```
library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=Server_Name; Database=DB_Name;Uid=; Pwd=; trusted_connection=yes")
initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from MyTable;"))
odbcClose(channel)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the github benchmarking link. I am working with a table that contains more than 500 columns, so the post in the link actually does agree with me in the part that says 'RODBC fails dramatically to extract all rows for big table'.
I will look deeper into the rsqlserver library.

Comment: Sure. Or, maybe bulk insert / export. Check out this link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15

What they are doing, I believe, is grabbing thousands or tens of thousands of rows, in batches, rather than row by row, which as you can see, is painfully slow. One thought would be to bulk download from SQL Server, to a CSV file on your client machine, and then push that object into R. I haven't reied that, but in theory that should work.